# how to create category in joomla 2.5 programmatically using external php file

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have loaded joomla environment using external php file.

```
<?php
require_once('configuration.php');
// Create a JConfig object
$config = new JConfig();
// Use the object in a meaningful way
```

?>

Now how to create a new category under a parent category..

Answer (score 1):

You should use joomla's API because there is an asset table which you don't want to screw
Same question was already posted here: [How to add categories in Joomla 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003979/how-to-add-categories-in-joomla-2-5)

An example how this could be handled check: https://gist.github.com/mbabker/3211464

with the setLocation, you can set the parent category

How you get the Joomla Framework in your external file can be found here: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_stand-alone_application_using_the_Joomla!_Framework

Hope this helps your needs

Comment: I have nearly 900 joomla categories to be added but i cant type them manually ,what will be the  function for adding new category ABC under XYZ.

Comment: How about you create a function to addCategory and you can pass the parameters 'categoryname', 'parentcategory'... this will then add your new category by setting : $category->title="ABC" and $category->setLocation(1, 'XYZ'); then it stores it... now you only need to read wherever your categories are stored(db/file), fetch trough the resultset and for every result call the function to add the Category